# Play FLV in ActionScript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flv, haxe

I am very new to Flash and Actionscript. I am trying to simply play an FLV file. I have the following:

```
import flash.MovieClip;
import flash.Video;
import flash.NetConnection;
import flash.NetStream;


class Program {
private var container_mc : MovieClip;
private var video_mc : Video;


public function new() {


   var mc : flash.MovieClip = flash.Lib.current;

          container_mc =  flash.Lib._root.attachMovie("VideoContainer", "container_mc", 0);

          container_mc.attachMovie("VideoClip", "video_mc", 1);

    var my_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

    my_nc.connect(null);

    trace(my_nc.isConnected);

    var my_ns:NetStream = new NetStream(my_nc);

    //my_ns.setBufferTime(1);



    container_mc.video_mc.attachVideo(my_ns);

    my_ns.play("default.flv"); 

    trace("Done"); 
}
 public static function main()
 {
     new Program();
 }
}
```

I get the "Done" trace message back but no video playback. I simple have a black box in the browser window. Can someone help me out? Thanks a ton!

-Nick

Comment: can you add my_ns.onStatus = function(o:Object) { trace(o.code); }; to your code and add the output to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You should double check to make sure you have two movieclips in the library that have the linkage IDs that you're trying to attach.

You'll need both:

```
VideoContainer
VideoClip
```

Answer (score 0):

new is a keyword, so you can't use it as a function name!!

Answer (score -1):

I hope that .. the code bellow .. will .. work very well ..

I use the fallowing .. preBuildCommand .. into my project .. FAG EXPLORER FLV.fdp

```
<preBuildCommand>"$(ToolsDir)\swfmill\swfmill.exe" simple "library/video.xml"
```

"library/video.swf"

To be continued

FAG = FREE ACADEMIC GAMES

When I use the line

```
<preBuildCommand>"$(ToolsDir)\swfmill\swfmill.exe" simple "library/video.xml"
```

"library/video.swf"

then

the project must contain the lines below

```
<library>
    <asset path="Library\video.swf" />
</library>
```

Observations:

swfmill.exe .. creates .. the file .. video.swf .. into the directory .. library

(library  .. is  .. placed next to the project file)

swfmill.exe uses the file .. video.xml .. to create .. the file .. video.swf

The code of the file  .. video.swf .. is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<movie version="7">
<frame>
    <library>
        <clip id="VideoDisplay">
            <frame>
                <video id="VideoSurface" width="854" height="480"/>
                <place id="VideoSurface" name="video"/>
            </frame>
        </clip>
    </library>
</frame>
</movie>
```

To be continued

```
import util.VideoDisplay;

class util.Instances
{
function Instances() {

 //  _root.Fdisplay_MC

     _root.createEmptyMovieClip ("Fdisplay_MC", _root.getNextHighestDepth());

     _root.Fdisplay_MC._alpha = 50;

//
 var

 Fdisplay:VideoDisplay = new VideoDisplay(null, _root.Fdisplay_MC, "Fdisplay", 1);

_root.Fdisplay = Fdisplay; _root.Fdisplay._x = 5; _root.Fdisplay._y = 0;

    _root.Fdisplay.setVolume(100);

//
_root.Fdisplay_MC.onPress = function()

{
  if (_root.b_pause) _root.b_pause = 0 else _root.b_pause = 1;

     _root.Fdisplay.pause();

}// _root.Fdisplay_MC.onPress = function()

}// function Instances() {

}// class util.Instances

To be continued
```

/**
* The initial code is from http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?t=321 
*       Part 3. Streaming FLV videos (FlashDevelop/SWFMILL only)

```
    I put the fallowing code into the initial class util.VideoDisplay  


// attach audio
display.attachAudio(ns);    

audio_sound = new Sound(display);


/**
* Get time in video
*/

public function pos():Number

{
    return ns.time;
}


public function setVolume(vol:Number):Void

{               
    audio_sound.setVolume(vol);
}

private var audio_sound:Sound;
```

*/

```
class util.VideoDisplay
{
//{ PUBLIC MEMBERS

/**
* 
* Create a new video display surface
*/

function VideoDisplay(targetURI:String, parent:MovieClip, name:String, depth:Number, initObj)

{           
    display = parent.attachMovie("VideoDisplay", name, depth, initObj);

    // create video stream

    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect(targetURI);

    ns = new NetStream(nc);

    // attach the video stream to the video object
    display.video.attachVideo(ns);

    // attach audio
    display.attachAudio(ns);    

    audio_sound = new Sound(display);       

} // VideoDisplay(targetURI:String, parent:MovieClip, name:String, depth:Number, initObj)


/**
* Video surface dimensions
*/
function setSize(width:Number, heigth:Number):Void
{
    display.video._width = width;
    display.video._height = heigth;
}
/**
* Video clip position
*/
function setLocation(x:Number, y:Number):Void
{
    display._x = x;
    display._y = y;
}

/**
* Start streaming
* @param    url FLV file
* @param    bufferTime  Buffer size (optional) 
*/
public function play(url:String, bufferTime:Number):Void
{
    if (bufferTime != undefined) ns.setBufferTime(bufferTime);
    ns.play(url);
}
/**
* Pause streaming
*/
public function pause():Void
{
    ns.pause();
}
/**
* Seek position in video
*/
public function seek(offset:Number):Void
{
    ns.seek(offset);
}   

/**
* Get time in video
*/

public function pos():Number

{
    return ns.time;
}

/**
* Close the video
*/

public function close():Void

{
    ns.close();
}   

    public function setVolume(vol:Number):Void

{               
    audio_sound.setVolume(vol);
}

//}

//{ PRIVATE MEMBERS 

private var display:MovieClip;
private var nc:NetConnection;
private var ns:NetStream;

private var audio_sound:Sound;  

//}

}
```