# How to play flv video in android?

Tags: android, video, webview, flv

I want to display my **FLV** *video* in **emulator**. Anybody who have already work on this?
Basically I need to play video from particular **URL** and **assets** *folder*. So just help on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play a FLV video using the flash plugin inside a WebView. [See here](http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications).

Hope this will help you.

**Edit:**

These are done using Action Scripts.

[Call the Action Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367939/is-there-a-way-to-call-actionscript-on-android)
 [Play flv using Action Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787360/play-flv-in-actionscript-2)
 [flv programming](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flvplayback_programming.html)
 [Also this](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/24895-flv-player.html)

Comment: i have already try this but i cant get success please help on this

Comment: See this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753167/play-flv-file-in-videoview-in-android.. I wil try to get u some sample code for tat

Comment: i have try all google result .... 
can you help me in collaboration of http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications example?

Comment: Ok..Have u gone thro' this link which plays the flash content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431351/how-do-i-pause-flash-content-in-an-android-webview-when-my-activity-isnt-visible

Comment: i have also try this.i already show you that , i have all kind of search from web.

Comment: See in that question, there is comment tat u can do this using action script.. U can try tat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504088/how-do-i-fire-an-intent-to-start-a-flv-or-swf-to-flash-player-10-1

Comment: In tat case u can refer this sites so that u can get an idea, i updated my answer for those reference

Comment: you just searching from google and try try to help. but ineed some thing  properly and exact solution

Comment: Im not done much about flv, i have used other players only. I just tried to help u. I got some links, check it out if it is useful for u..

Comment: you just try to sample logic to solve this issue but it cant happen like this way it cant get proper manner

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround which will also allow you to play from a local asset resource, please read my answer to this similar question for a full solution:

[Problem to load flv video in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview/6855609#6855609)

Answer (score 0):

I used [flv.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js) in the webpage to make the html support flv video file without flash. Then use XWalkView something like webview in android studio to load the webpage. [Use WWalkView.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858878/6521116).